# How to send email through Gmail API ? Go

Tags: email, go, gmail

I'm trying to send email through the [gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) using  [Go](http://golang.org) but I find the documentation quite flawed/ confusing. For once I don't see the receipt field nor the email body.

I don't need to upload anything so I find [Simple upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#multipart), Multipart upload, Resumable upload methods totally useless. Is there any clear demo (with the data /params required e.g. a cURL payload)  ?

As a side note I'm not sure if I'm the only one thinking this but the google apis seem quite the worst out there (in terms of usability) unless there is a library available. The Gmail API seems a good candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use directly the Go library for GMail API:
http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/gmail/v1

(You have even simpler libraries like [SlyMarbo/gmail](https://github.com/SlyMarbo/gmail) or [njern/gogmail](https://github.com/njern/gogmail))

Comment: Concerning the 1st one there doesn't seem to be a send method isn't it ? The 2nd one is SMTP based

Comment: @hey it has a `Send()` method, in the gmail-gen source: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/source/browse/gmail/v1/gmail-gen.go#2243

Comment: Indeed... there it is. Is it a good practice to re-use the types even if 80% of the fields are not used by that method ? As far as I can see on the Message[1] type only Payload and ThreadId is/may be used by "Send" [1]http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/gmail/v1#Message

Comment: @hey true, it might be a bit overkill, I suppose Message is used for reading/receiving as well, where all those fields are used.