# How to send GTLRGmail_Message with attachment

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail, gmail-api

After searching a while i have manage to send a email but without attachment as follows:

```
NSString *messageString =                              @"From: \"From Email USer Name\" <fromEmail>\r\n";
messageString = [messageString stringByAppendingString:@"To: \"To Email User Name\" <ToEmail>\r\n"];
messageString = [messageString stringByAppendingString:@"Subject: New stuff\r\n"];
messageString = [messageString stringByAppendingString:@"Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n"];
messageString = [messageString stringByAppendingString:@"Hello my friend, \n can you please call me when have free time. \nMark."];

NSData *data = [messageString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64Encoded = GTLREncodeWebSafeBase64(data);


GTLRGmail_Message *message = [[GTLRGmail_Message alloc] init];

message.raw = base64Encoded;

GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesSend *query = [GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesSend queryWithObject:message userId:@"myEmailAddress" uploadParameters:nil];

[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket * _Nonnull callbackTicket, id  _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable callbackError) {
      NSLog(@"%@",callbackError);
 }];
```

i have tried to add `GTLRUploadParameters` as follows:

```
GTLRUploadParameters *params = [GTLRUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:imageData MIMEType:@"message/rfc822"];
```

but still no success, i have tried to split the message in multiple `GTLRGmail_MessagePartBody` and add them to container `GTLRGmail_MessagePartBody` as a `message.payload` like:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_1253" ofType:@"jpg"];

/***************************** create a imageData part ******************/

NSData *imagedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *imageBase64String = GTLREncodeWebSafeBase64(imagedata);
GTLRGmail_MessagePartBody *bodyImage = [[GTLRGmail_MessagePartBody alloc] init];
bodyImage.data = imageBase64String;
bodyImage.size = @(imagedata.length);

GTLRGmail_MessagePart *imagePart = [[GTLRGmail_MessagePart alloc] init];
imagePart.body = bodyImage;
imagePart.mimeType = @"image/jpeg";
imagePart.filename = @"IMG_1253";


/***************************** create a message part ******************/

NSString *messageString = @"Hello my friend, \n can you please call me when have free time. \nMark.";
NSData *dataMessage = [messageString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64EncodedMessage = GTLREncodeWebSafeBase64(dataMessage);

GTLRGmail_MessagePartBody *bodyText = [[GTLRGmail_MessagePartBody alloc] init];
bodyText.data = base64EncodedMessage;
bodyText.size = @(dataMessage.length);


GTLRGmail_MessagePart *messagePart = [[GTLRGmail_MessagePart alloc] init];
messagePart.body = bodyText;
messagePart.mimeType = @"text/plain";

/***************************** create a payload part ******************/

GTLRGmail_MessagePartHeader *toHeader = [[GTLRGmail_MessagePartHeader alloc] init];
toHeader.name = @"to";
toHeader.value = @"userEmail";

GTLRGmail_MessagePart *payload = [[GTLRGmail_MessagePart alloc] init];
payload.mimeType = @"multipart/mixed; boundary=\"IMG_1253\"";
payload.parts = @[messagePart, imagePart];


GTLRGmail_Message *message = [[GTLRGmail_Message alloc] init];
message.payload = payload;

GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesSend *query = [GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesSend queryWithObject:message userId:@"myEmail" uploadParameters:nil];

[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket * _Nonnull callbackTicket, id  _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable callbackError) {

    NSData *data  = callbackError.userInfo[@"data"];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:0];

    NSLog(@"%@",string);
}];
```

but in this case i get :`Code=400 "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"`, if i add the `base64Encoded` to `message.raw` from previous solution i get the email but no attachment
what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363312/how-to-send-email-through-gmail-api-go?rq=1

Comment: @Amanpreet yes i checked that and many others , but no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so the solution is a modified a little the [Vea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379576/vea) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38261223/2050181) is not the prettier one but:

```
GTLRUploadParameters *uploadParam = [[GTLRUploadParameters alloc] init];
uploadParam.MIMEType = @"message/rfc822";
uploadParam.data = [self getFormattedRawMessage];

GTLRGmail_Message *message = [[GTLRGmail_Message alloc] init];

GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesSend *query = [GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesSend queryWithObject:message userId:@"constantin.saulenco@gmail.com" uploadParameters:uploadParam];

[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket * _Nonnull callbackTicket, id  _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable callbackError) {

    NSData *data  = callbackError.userInfo[@"data"];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:0];

    NSLog(@"%@",string);
}];
```

and `getFormattedRawMessage` :

```
- (NSData *)getFormattedRawMessage
{
    // Date string
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString *finalDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@\r\n", strDate];

    // From string
    NSString *from = @"From: <constantin.saulenco@gmail.com>\r\n";

    // To string
    NSString *to = @"To: <constantin.saulenco@mobiversal.com>\r\n";

    // CC string
    NSString *cc = @"";

    // BCC string
    NSString *bcc = @"";

    // Subject string
    NSString *subject = @"Subject: New stuff\r\n\r\n";

    // Body string
    NSString *body = @"Hello my friend, \n can you please call me when have free time. \nMark. \r\n";

    // Final string to be returned
    NSString *rawMessage = @"";

    // Send as "multipart/mixed"
    NSString *contentTypeMain = @"Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"project\"\r\n";

    // Reusable Boundary string
    NSString *boundary = @"\r\n--project\r\n";

    // Body string
    NSString *contentTypePlain = @"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n";

    // Combine strings from "finalDate" to "body"
    rawMessage = [[[[[[[[[contentTypeMain stringByAppendingString:finalDate] stringByAppendingString:from]stringByAppendingString:to]stringByAppendingString:cc]stringByAppendingString:bcc]stringByAppendingString:subject]stringByAppendingString:boundary]stringByAppendingString:contentTypePlain]stringByAppendingString:body];


    // Image Content Type string
    NSString *contentTypeJPG = boundary;
    contentTypeJPG = [contentTypeJPG stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"%@\"\r\n",@"IMG_1253.jpg"]];
    contentTypeJPG = [contentTypeJPG stringByAppendingString:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"];

    // PNG image data
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1253.jpg"];
    NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
    NSString *imageBase64String = GTLREncodeBase64(jpegData);
    NSString *pngString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n",imageBase64String];
    contentTypeJPG = [contentTypeJPG stringByAppendingString:pngString];

    // Add to raw message
    rawMessage = [rawMessage stringByAppendingString:contentTypeJPG];


    // End string
    rawMessage = [rawMessage stringByAppendingString:@"\r\n--project--"];

    return [rawMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

but i still what to know how to use `GTLRGmail_MessagePartBody` and `GTLRGmail_MessagePartHeader` for `message.payload`